# Sonata Admin extending User admin class and not using generated bundle

Tags: symfony, admin, sonata

I had some trouble extending user admin when i tried to use the classes in my bundle and not in the generated bundle (Application/Sonata/UserBundle).
I don't know if my solution is good but it works for me.

Here is the procedure:

- First the config:

```html
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"
        # added for sonata user
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        # added for sonata user
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
#  FosRest configuration
fos_rest:
    view:
        formats:
            rss: false
            xml: false
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
# SonataAdmin configuration
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # Enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)

sonata_user:
    security_acl: false
    manager_type: orm # can be orm or mongodb
    class:
        user: Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Entity\User
        group: Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Entity\Group
    admin:
        user:
            class:          Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle
        group:
            class:          Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Admin\GroupAdmin
            controller:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD
            translation:    SonataUserBundle

fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Entity\User
    # use this option when easy extending the bundle (app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle --dest=src)
    #user_class:     Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser
    group:
        group_class:   Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Entity\Group
        #group_class:   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager
    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

- UserAdmin class; same with GroupAdmin class

```html
<?php
/**
 * Created by razvan.
 * Date: 1/16/15
 * Time: 1:53 PM
 */

namespace Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;


class UserAdmin extends BaseUserAdmin
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->with('General')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->end()
            // .. more fields
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {

        $formMapper
            ->with('User data')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('plainPassword', 'text', array('required' => false))
            ->end()
            // .. more fields
        ;

        if (!$this->getSubject()->hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
            $formMapper
                ->with('Management')
                ->add('roles', 'sonata_security_roles', array(
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'required' => false
                ))
                ->add('locked', null, array('required' => false))
                ->add('expired', null, array('required' => false))
                ->add('enabled', null, array('required' => false))
                ->add('credentialsExpired', null, array('required' => false))
                ->end()
            ;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filterMapper)
    {
        $filterMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('locked')
            ->add('email')
        ;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
      // overide defaults
    }
}
```

- User class; same wirh Group class

```html
<?php


namespace Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Entity;

use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Class User
 * @package Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_user")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Now in Resources\config create a folder named "doctrine" and then add the folowing files:

```html
First file is named Group.orm.xml

Inser the following into the file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Entity\Group" table="fos_user_group">

        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>

    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>

Second file is User.orm.xml

Insert the following:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Wf\Bundle\TestsBundle\Entity\User" table="fos_user_user">

        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>

    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Be careful to change the path to your own and clear the cache.

Comment: Seems to be working without the doctrine xml mapping now :D

Comment: you should edit this question to be just a question, then you can answer yourself and mark that answer as correct. Thanks.